# What does `SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped` from `netstat -s` mean

Tags: netstat

I could found `437 SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped` from `netstat -s` from the server on my server which runs nginx.

I found this explanation from the man page: `--statistics, -s, Display summary statistics for each protocol.`

Then what does this count `437` mean, is it a snapshot or a summed up count for some time period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx accepts connections very quickly, but in extremely high-traffic situations, a connection backlog can still happen at the system level (which is a distinct bottleneck from the application-level connection handling) When this occurs, new connections will be refused.

"SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped" is a symptom that your Nginx drops the packets. My advice is to first monitor the Nginx active connections using `ngx_http_stub_status_module`[1]. Then identify current system wide open file descriptors and adjust kernel parameters accordingly.

The connection queue size can be increased by modifying the `somaxconn` and `tcp_max_syn_backlog` kernel variables. Please refer these valuable resources[2][3] for more information.

- [1] https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html
- [2] http://engineering.chartbeat.com/2014/01/02/part-1-lessons-learned-tuning-tcp-and-nginx-in-ec2/
- [3] https://www.scalyr.com/community/guides/how-to-monitor-nginx-the-essential-guide

Answer (score 0):

Usually wmem and rmem defaults are 212992 bytes. Apparently not enough on busy server. Raised to 8MB and the problem disappeared.

```
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_default=8388608
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=8388608
```

See [What causes “SYN to LISTEN sockets dropped”?](https://serverfault.com/questions/646604/what-causes-syn-to-listen-sockets-dropped).